# Recursively requiring modules in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

So, let's say I have two classes, each of which requires the other:

Department.js:

```
const Person = require("./Person");
class Department{
  constructor(id){
    this.personel = getPersonel(id).map(person => new Person(person));
  }
}
```

Person.js

```
const Department = require("./Department");
class Person {
  constructor(id){
    this.department = new Department(getDeptOfPerson(id));
  }
}
const person = new Person(1);
const coworkers = person.department.personel;
```

Now, this doesn't work, and I can kinda understand why. It says "Person" is not a constructor at Department.js. However, if I put both classes in the same file, it works just fine.

So; my question is, how do I work around this? I'd really rather not keep both of these classes in the same file -- is there a better way?

I'm running the latest version of Node.

Comment: If you have circular dependencies then you are doing something wrong.  If a Person needs to create new Department and a Department needs to create a new Person, then both classes have way too much responsibility (they should only create themselves). Ideally you would want a third factory class which is responsible for creating and passing instances of Person and Department to the correct instances, instead of having each of the respective classes instantiate them directly. As is your code is so tightly coupled that having separate classes seems redundant.

Comment: @Fraser I don't understand how I should design said factory in order to not just push the problem back. In my mind it makes sense that `Department` would have a property `personel` that would return `Person`s that have all the methods of a Person available to them and it would also make sense that a Person would have a property `department` witch has the methods of a department available to it... It however does not make any sense to me to have them both in the same class, so I don't see the redundancy...

Comment: See the given answer, a factory pattern is fairly common in software design , as is the concept of decoupling classes. Here findDepartment, and findPerson act as creator classes for the relevant entities. Meaning that Person and Department are loosely coupled.

Comment: "just push the problem back" - it is not pushing the problem back, it is encapsulating the functionality in a way that stops a Person requiring Department and Department requiring Person...If some "Manage" class requires Person and Department this is fine - as it doesn't tie the two classes together directly in the way you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate initializing objects from fetching data:

```
// types/Department.js
class Department {
  constructor(id, personnel) {
    this.id = id;
    this.personnel = personnel;
  }
}

// types/Person.js
class Person {
  constructor(id, department) {
    this.id = id;
    this.department = department;
  }
}

// findDepartment.js
const Department = require('./types/Department');
const Person = require('./types/Person');

function findDepartment(id) {
  const personnel = getPersonnel(id).map(person => new Person(person));
  return new Department(id, personnel);
}

// findPerson.js
const Department = require('./types/Department');
const Person = require('./types/Person');

function findPerson(id) {
  const department = getDeptOfPerson(id);
  return new Person(id, department);
}
```

These can even go back on the types (`findDepartment.js` → `Department.js`, `Department.findDepartment = function (id) { …`) if you really want.